# Install elastica-bundle It require already installed versions from symfony/form

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony, foselasticabundle

Sorry for my english.

I'm trying to install elastica-bundle in my Symfony application, and I get the following error:
friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle 3.1.0 requires ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/form[2.1.x-dev, 2.2.x-dev, .... symfony/form but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

My composer.json require is:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3",
    "components/jquery": "^2.1",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/finder": "^3.0",
    "symfony/serializer": "^3.0",
    "symfony/form": "^3.1",
    "symfony/console": "=2.8.6",
    "symfony/property-access": "^3.1",
    "ruflin/elastica": "^3.2",
    "psr/log": "^1.0"
},
```

and my AppKernel.php

```
$bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
    new \UPD\UserBundle\UserBundle(),
    new \FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    new \Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
    new \Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
    new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    );
```

I don't understand where is the problem, because symfony/form is installed with a higher version.

Someone can be help me?

Thanks for all, I am quite newbie.

Answer (score 1):

The message `friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle 3.1.0 requires ~2.1` means Elastica bundle requires at least Symfony 2.1, but always a 2.XX version.
The `~` operator was the Composer best practice, however many popular bundles are not compatible with Symfony 3.0 "only" because of it.

For now no SF3.0 compatible version of Elastica Bundle was released.
The 3.2 will be, so you can add to your `composer.json` temporary:
`"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "dev-master as 3.2"`

Hope your project won't be live immediately, since it is still a dev version!
WCS scenario, pick a commit, test everything is wokring there, and then do:
`"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "dev-master#COMMIT_HASH"`